# Putting bounds on predictions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, predictive-models

I want to build an ML pipeline that is going to classify new data before making a prediction. I want the classification process to put a bound on what the final prediction will be. Say that I have a new datapoint and I want to predict its value between [-1, 1]. I want to first classify it as high [0.5, 1], middle [-0.5,0.5] or low [-1,-0.5] before I make the final prediction. Searching google has only led me to pages on prediction intervals Does anyone know of any module, literature, or even if anyone could write up a brief pseudocode for this to set me in the right direction, it would be of great help.

Comment: classification or regression?

Comment: I want to classify before regressing. So that the final prediction will be contained in a pre-defined boundary